# Four similar tags relating to metalworking

Tags: discussion, specific-tag, tags

I was writing a question about working with iron, and noticed that there seemed to be quite a lot of tags relating to the topic, some of which seemed conflicting:

- [metals](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/metals) (147)
- [metalworking](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/metalworking) (56)
- [forging](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/forging) (7)
- [iron](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/iron) (1)

Specifically, [metalworking](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/metalworking) seems to conflict with [forging](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/forging), and [metals](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/metals) seems to be a superset of [iron](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/iron), which has only one question and seems unnecessary.

I don't have the score needed in any of these tags to suggest synonyms (and probably wouldn't do so without asking on meta anyway), but I think they could probably use some cleaning up.

I'd suggest keeping [metals](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/metals) and [metalworking](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/metalworking), making [forging](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/forging) a synonym of the latter, and getting rid of [iron](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/iron). It seems [forging](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/forging) is almost always used with [metalworking](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/metalworking) anyway, and I don't see it adding too much.

Is this something that should be cleaned up?

Comment: Also, I noticed while tagging _this_ question that we have [meta-tag:tags], [meta-tag:specific-tag], and [meta-tag:tag] (with just 4 uses, always alongside [meta-tag:specific-tag]) :p

Answer (score 5):

Thanks for bringing this up. Consolidating them as you've said makes sense.

It's good housekeeping, merging two minor tags into their parent tags. To catastrophize for a second, if we don't we run the risk of separate minor tags for every metal and alloy, plus every metalworking technique. That would create a lot of noise for little value.

If we find ourselves in a circumstance where we need to make those distinctions then we can recreate the tags when they are needed.

While we're at it we should remove the redundant `tag` tag.

Comment: I for one think it's about time the smiths, metal workers, tinkers, farriers, wheelwrights and other assorted & ironic trades clean up their tags!

Comment: Merging and synonymization done